# How do i justify myself to a prospective employer why I'm quitting a job that i joined two months back?

Tags: interviewing, human-resources, india, career-switch, employment-gaps

1. I'm an indian and i finished my graduation in 2015. Then joined a service based MNC in feb 2016 and worked there for a year and half. I quit the company(Aug 2017) in order to pursue higher studies. But unfortunately, it did not pan out and since i already had previous experience, i came back to IT industry(Software quality assurance, to be specific).
2. This took all in all 16 months

   - 5months - GATE preparation(Aug 2017 to Jan 2018)
   - 2months - waiting for exam result(Feb and Mar 2018)
   - 2months - Sisters Marriage(April and May 2018)
   - 2Months - Wasted(June and July 2018)
   - 5Moths - Joined a course to get back in touch with all the things needed for my next job(Aug 2018 to Dec 2018)
   - Got job in Jan 2019
     So, all in all, a gap of one and half years.
3. I joined a second company(startup) and was working there when they removed me citing performance issues(Actually it was something to do with my manager, that i came to know about later). They removed me in jan 2020.
4. My grandmother passed away in feb 2020 and it took all feb and half of march to finish all the rituals. So could not focus on job search. Then the covid-19 hit us.
5. I was preparing meanwhile and got myself a job in June 2020.
   Now my issue is, the people in this company are ok and work is also not that great. I don't see a learning curve here. So i'm thinking to look for a different job.

Should i put this company in my resume or just say that i have worked only till Jan 2020 and because of covid-19 could not get a job.

And if i DO PUT this in my resume, then it will reflect very badly on my part as i have two gaps in my career now.
I'm confused as to what to do now? I have around 2 and half years of exp. If i do continue here then it will just add years to my resume and not skills.

Any help/guidance/advice is very much appreciated.

P.S: I'm seeing many downvotes here. So here are some of the threads that i have gone through. Any other things that needs to be added to not get downvotes?

[job change-transitioning to a new job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/110094/how-to-transition-to-a-new-job-after-a-failed-short-stay-at-a-company?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[job change after 1.5 month in estonia](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/125252/how-to-justify-changing-job-after-1-5-month)

- The reason i'm looking for a job change is that, this is a startup and they are hiring and firing like there is no tomorrow and i feel that if the worst was to come then it would affect my career in the long run. Hence i'm looking to join a company where i can stay for a couple of years at the least.

Comment: FYI an update. I have been asked to leave the company just after 2 months of my joining citing the reason of performance issue. Also two others have also been released and 6 other new people have been hired. It's good that they released me. I would not like to work in such a company who doesn't value it's employees. 
Thank you everyone for taking time out and responding. 

If possible, someone with enough access can close this thread/question.

Answer (score 3):

> "Now my issue is, the people in this company are ok and work is also not that great. I don't see a learning curve here."

It's an absolute basic of being a software engineer that ***on your own*** you have to / must continually and aggressively advance your knowledge.

Nobody can help you with this. If you expect your current or any company to do it, that is a misconception.

You must adopt self-learning, self-challenging, or it will be impossible to make it in software.

Enjoy your current job which seems fine, build stability and save money for a year or two.

Regarding your misconception that this particular company has no learning curve, accept that you have a misconception.

Programmers must and can only have ***their own*** learning curve.

Once you let go of the misconception, my guess is you will have tremendous career satisfaction and advancement.

Comment: Thanks @Fattie, for taking your time to reply.
I would like to give some clarifications as i think i have projected myself in a wrong light as can be seen by the downvotes on the question(Please also let me know what changes should i do in order for the question to be comprehensible?)

**It's an absolute basic of being a software engineer that on your own you have to/must continually and aggressively advance your knowledge.**
1) I know that 'I'm on my own' not only in IT industry but in general even in life. I'm not expecting people to spoon feed me( If that's the idea you got from above).

Comment: Continued part of the above comment:
**You must adopt self-learning, self-challenging, or it will be impossible to make it in software.**
2) In this current company, I'm trying to learn as much as possible. About the domain, about how people are interacting/communicating remotely(As this is my first time working remotely) and other things as such(Both technical and softskills).
Not only here anywhere i go i always strive to learn continuously. I have taken courses on udemy and courseera and practicing and upskilling myself in this regard.
I know how hard it is to survive in todays world.

Comment: Continued part of the above comments:
**Programmers must and can only have their own learning curve.**
3) Regarding having my own learning curve,I agree that it is possible to learn without depending on the organization but only upto some extent because i will be giving 10-11 hours of my time to the organization and i would like to expect at least some kind of learning in return and not just money. I guess i'm not wrong in expecting at least this much, let alone all other perks and benefits,because that's what all this is right? A mutually beneficial exchange, Skills for Money. 
Continued..

Comment: Continued part of the above comments:
And moreover i'm ready to accept whatever misconception/s or wrong notions that i have and ready to accept that i might be completely at fault at times, provided someone tell me in what way/s i'm wrong and in what ways these are misconception/s.

Because as far as i know, most people(Including myself) would still consider me as fresher(albeit with a little bit of knowledge) and i want to grow in my career. Hence i usually come to forums. 
Plus there is nothing wrong in having healthy discussions and i'm always up for it.

Comment: The reason why i'm looking for a change is, this is a startup and these guys are hiring and firing left and right, like there is no tomorrow. And i fear that if i come under their radar(Doesn't mean that i'm not working promptly here) then it would be bad for my career(with already a long gap) and a bit unstable career(Short stints in past companies). It won't look good on my resume irrespective of the skills that i posses. 
Hence the above question.
There are people here, with far more experience and knowledge than me. I hope i'm not wrong in requesting for some advice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that 2 months is longer than "just pretend it didn't happen" lengths of time, although the pandemic does give you more of a get-out then you'd have normally as it's a ready-made excuse to be out of work that much longer. The flipside of the pandemic effect though is that arguably the fact that you *got* employment during a time when people are losing their jobs all over the place actually works in your favor. Your first employment "gap" isn't really bad - you made a choice to go back to study, albeit one that didn't work out as you'd hoped, re-frame June-Jul '18 as "took some time to evaluate my options" instead of "Wasted" and it's nothing that sets of any huge alarm bells IMO.

If you do decide to look for other work then "I'm looking for a job where I can continue to learn new skills" isn't an awful reason to be looking for a new job, in fact in lots of scenarios it's a pretty good one. What I would consider though is whether you're being too dismissive of "adding years" vs adding skills, while learning new skills is important there's a lot to be said for improving the skills you already have. There's a very good reason why someone with say 2 years experience in a given skill is more sought after than someone with say 2 months - and there's nothing to stop you doing some outside learning of new skills that interest you in the meantime.

If you stayed in your current role for even another 6-12 months you are going to eliminate all your concerns about moving on so quickly and still be gaining valuable experience and stable employment history in the meantime - the relevance of both your gaps is going to be diminished substantially in that time.

Comment: "If you stayed in your current role for even another 6-12 months you are going to eliminate all your concerns about moving on so quickly" .. quite so.

Comment: In addition, in this climate, it might take 6-12 months to find the next job.  Or not.  But do find the next job before leaving this one.

Comment: Thanks @motosubatsu for your reply. The reason i'm looking for a job change is that, this is a startup and they are hiring and firing like there is no tomorrow and i feel that if the worst was to come then it would affect my career in the long run.
 Hence i'm looking to join a company where i can stay for a couple of years at the least. (I have added this part in the question now). 

I know that the situation is not good right now and even i don't want to go through the hassle of interviewing again for days without knowing when i'll be getting a new job.