# Explaining change of career in an Interview

Tags: career-switch

How should one approach the question of change of career in an interview? What appropriate reasons can one provide that would not look bad on them. To briefly explain the situation:

My friend is a Medical professional who worked briefly in a private hospital. Soon the workplace environment made it impossible to continue and self-practice was not a viable option.

It has been a year now and he just got an interview call from a government institute in insurance sector.

**Edit:**

Since the question has been closed due to being deemed duplicate, let me clarify that question is not about "change of jobs". My friend is changing career from a *doctor* to a *desk officer*. That is, he will no longer be practicing as a doctor.

Nonetheless, Lawrence Aiello's suggestion seems the best option.

Comment: see also: [Interviewing for jobs after a long (no work) period of absence?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14557/interviewing-for-jobs-after-a-long-no-work-period-of-absence)

Comment: "made it impossible to continue" is an interpretation which does not give us anything to give advice on. Please [edit] the question and stick to the facts.

Comment: The explanation you have given has fully explained why he does not want to work in that hospital, but not why he wouldn't want to do the same job for another employer. Are there no other hospital that he could work at?

Comment: He got the interview what does he need to explain?  They can tell from his resume he had a another type of job.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The same answer as any interview question: use it as an opportunity to show how you can help the employer and the value you can bring. For example:

"I used to love working in the hospital because **insert reasons here**, but have since discovered I found a passion in the insurance field, and can use the skills I have gained in the hospital to help your organization accomplish xyz."

Comment: I would say almost the same thing, except change "no longer see myself growing" to "found that I was much more passionate about {new field}."

Comment: I agree. How's it look now?

Comment: Works for me.  Can't upvote twice, though.  :)

Comment: I agree. The OP's friend needs to work out their own  positive reasons for why the OP's friend wants to switch to practicing in insurance. Nobody can work out these reasons for him because nobody knows him as well as he knows himself. It's up to him to get the prospective employer excited at the prospect of his joining the company because of what he can do for said prospective employer.

Comment: @WesleyLong I stuffed LwrenceAiello's ballot box with my upvote for you :)